# Cómo compruebo si la cuenta existe en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

He intentado solo con *count($result) > 0* pero no funciona, con *strlen* y tampoco y este ejemplo tampoco me funciona, cómo puedo hacer para comprobar si la cuenta existe?

```js
$result = mysqli_query($base,"SELECT * FROM $users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'");

if (count(mysql_fetch_array($result)) > 1) {
    echo "Login...";
}
```

Comment: ¿Si haces un `var_dump` a `$result` que obtienes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema en tu código es que **estás usando la antigua función `mysql_fetch_array` (sin la `i`), la cual estaría obsoleta**.

Por otra parte, la forma más segura y a la vez eficaz de saber si hay registros es **contando**.

Además, para prevenir riesgo de *Inyección SQL*, considera usar **consultas preparadas**.

Así debería funcionar:

```
$total=0;
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
/* crear una sentencia preparada */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($base, $sql)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $password);
    /* ejecutar la consulta */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    /* ligar variables de resultado */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $total);
    /* obtener valor */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
}
/* $total será 0 (valor inicial) o el total de filas encontradas) */
var_dump($total);
```

Para más detalles sobre las consultas preparadas en mysqli [consulta el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) y para entender el enorme riesgo que estamos previniendo al implementar este código, lee sobre el tema *Inyección SQL*.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($base, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // Aqui iria lo que sucederia si se cumple la condicion
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "Si hay un registro";
  }
} else {
  echo "0 resultados encontrados";
}
```

Espero te pueda servir ;)