# Cómo traer los datos de la cuenta con while

Tags: php, mysqli

Cuando inicia el login no me arroja los datos que quiero mostrar en este caso el *account_id* ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

```js
$account_email = $_POST['account_email'];
$account_password = $_POST['account_password'];

$account = 0;

$login_get = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $users WHERE account_email = ? AND account_password = ?";

$login_result = mysqli_prepare($base, $login_get);
    
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($login_result, "ss", $account_email, $account_password);

mysqli_stmt_execute($login_result);
   
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($login_result, $account);
   
mysqli_stmt_fetch($login_result);
    
if ($account > 0) {
    
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($list)) {
        
        echo $account_id;
        
    }
    
    mysqli_stmt_close($login_result);
    
}
```

Comment: Bueno te diré que inicialmente el problema es que tratas de hacerle echo a una variable que no esta definida previamente

Comment: No estas siquiera cargando la variable que tratas de mostrar

Comment: Y ese query devuelve un count... no devuelve ningun dato de la cuenta...

Comment: @gbianchi Cuál sería la solución?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mi respuesta a otra pregunta tuya: [Cómo compruebo si la cuenta existe en la base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/482854/29967) te indicaba que *la mejor forma de saber si un registro existe es* ***contando***.

Ahora bien, si lo que te interesa es otra cosa, (para este caso concreto obtener la columna `account_id`) tendrías que seleccionar esa columna en específico.

Te propongo esta solución, mejorando un poco el código y corrigiendo otros errores que indicaré al final:

```
#Evitaremos variables demasiado largas
$email = !empty($_POST['account_email']) ? $_POST['account_email'] : NULL;
$password = !empty($_POST['account_password']) ? $_POST['account_password'] : NULL;

$account = 0;
if ($email && $password) {
    $login_get = "SELECT account_id FROM $users WHERE account_email = ? AND account_password = ? LIMIT 1";
    $login_result = mysqli_prepare($base, $login_get); 
    #OJO al cambio de nombre de variables 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($login_result, "ss", $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($login_result); 
    #Se espera sólo una columna, vinculamos un resultado
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($account);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($login_result);  
    mysqli_stmt_close($login_result);    
}
#Usar $account, que será 0 o el resultado de la consulta
var_dump($account); #Only for test
```

#### Algunas consideraciones

1. En la instrucción SQL se está seleccionando la columna que interesa (`account_id`). Además de eso, he agregado intuitivamente `LIMIT 1`, dando por supuesto que esta consulta lo que busca es obtener una sola fila. Si me equivoco en esa intuición me lo dices y modifico la respuesta. Todo esto lo que busca es **optimizar el código**.
2. En relación con lo dicho en 1, aquí no usaremos un `while` para leer los resultados, porque se intuye que se espera una sola fila y en esos casos no hace falta `while`. Es importante que comprendas que lo que hace `mysqli_stmt_fetch` es mover el puntero de resultados y que hay dos formas de hacer esto: Si se espera más de una fila, lo aplicas por medio de `while`; si se espera una sola fila, lo aplicas directamente. Tu código está mal implementado en este sentido, proque usas `mysqli_stmt_fetch` con y sin `while`. En ese caso, si hubieran varias filas, la parte del `while` empezaría a leerte de la segunda fila en adelante, porque el primer `mysqli_stmt_fetch` ya movió el puntero una vez<sup>(1)</sup>.
3. No tiene sentido vincular la variable `$login_result` a un resultado con `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`. El propósito de ese método es vincular a variables cada columna que te arroje la consulta SQL. Por ejemplo, esta consulta espera **una columna** que sería `account_id`  y la estaríamos vinculando a la variable `$account`. Si se esperasen más columnas, **debes vincularlas a variables destinadas para ello**. **Tu variable `$login_result` representa la consulta preparada, no puedes usarla también para vincular el resultado de una de las columnas**. Sugiero que leas la documentación para evitar este tipo de errores que revelan desconocimiento sobre cómo funcionan las consultas preparadas en mysqli.

Si hay algo que no queda claro, pregunta en comentarios, debajo de esta respuesta.

---

**Notas:**

(1). Para más detalles sobre esto puedes consultar [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/329587/29967) y también [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/143420/29967).

Comment: A pesar del ejemplo no logro mostrar la id, es decir si el correo y la contraseña son correctas mostrar la id a traves de un echo, obviamente son muchos datos que necesito mostrar pero este es un ejemplo, lo sé hacer de la forma 'normal' pero con consultas preparadas me cuesta entender y lograrlo. ¿Exactamente a que debería de hacerle echo a esa consulta preparada para poder mostrar los datos?

Comment: @NuevoUsuario en la pregunta puse esto para prueba: `var_dump($account);`, ¿qué es lo que estás obteniendo actualmente? Aclara también a qué te refieres con *muchos datos*. Si esta consulta pudiera recibir varias filas entonces sí hay que incorporar la lectura con el `while`.

Comment: Cuando el email y password son válidos entonces quisiera obtener la id de esa cuenta, y demás datos de esa cuenta. Pero $account sólo muestra número y necesito es el texto también de los demás datos que vaya a obtener